# How to find a file on disk that contains virtual DLL functions?

Tags: c, winapi, dll, kernel

Say, on Windows 8.1 and up, for those virtual [API sets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt654040%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), or *umbrella libraries*, is there a way to find out which file on disk (i.e. DLL) the functions are actually from?

As an example, I can tell with a debugger that `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-1.dll` is redirected to `KERNELBASE.dll`

Comment: `LoadLibrary`+`GetModuleFileName`

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, thanks. I was trying to avoid LoadLibrary, or executing those modules. Although, is `LoadLibraryEx(DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES)` still supported?

Comment: yes `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` still supported

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks. I have two quick followups. 1. I tried to step into the LoadLibrary implementation on my Win10 and it seems like this DLL name redirection happens in `LdrpPreprocessDllName()` method. Do you know if it is exported from any system DLL? Or is it just an internal function. I can't seem to find any exports with that symbol.

Comment: And 2. I need this virtual DLL name resolution for a project that may deal with reversing malware, and thus my concern of not executing anything in the DLL itself. Have you reversed the workings of LoadLibrary to know that it won't execute any code in the DLL if `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` flag is used?

Comment: yes, redirect was in `LdrpPreprocessDllName` or more concrete [`ApiSetResolveToHost`](https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/blob/master/src/BlackBoneDrv/apiset.h#L236) - this not exported api. exist way yourself parse api set, you can easy found links for internal structures, but it once was already changed

Comment: if you use `DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES` flag - any code from dll will be not executed - this is 100%

Comment: @RbMm: Thanks for confirming. And no, I don't want to implement it myself. It will be obsolete when the next major Windows update is out :)

Comment: @RbMm: Hey, one more follow-up on this subject. I implemented your suggestion in my actual project, but got a weird circular logic dependencies. Can you [take a look](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48184822/843732)?