# How to resolve circular dependency of a forwarded WinAPI?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, portable-executable

I'm trying to find a way to resolve a memory address and a DLL file name for a particular API when it's mapped into a process. Most of this can be resolved with the import/export tables in a DLL and by analyzing the Import Address Table of a mapped module. That is for most functions.

But the issue happens with some [forwarded functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060719-24/?p=30473). An example of such function happens to be `DeleteProcThreadAttributeList` on my Windows 10 system. So for instance, if I build a test 32-bit process with such function, or better yet, let's use a 32-bit version of `cmd.exe` from `c:\windows\syswow64\cmd.exe` image, and then try to analyze its import table. It turns out that this function is imported from the *API Set* with a virtual name `API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL`:

[image]

To find an actual file that it redirects to I do the following:

```
HMODULE hMM = ::LoadLibraryEx(L"API-MS-WIN-CORE-PROCESSTHREADS-L1-1-2.DLL", 
    NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
WCHAR buffModPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileNameEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), hMM, buffModPath, _countof(buffModPath));
::FreeLibrary(hMM);
```

Which gives me `buffModPath` as `C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL`.

Since I'm calling it from a 32-bit process, I now inspect the export table of `c:\windows\syswow64\KERNEL32.DLL` module:

[image]

that shows that `DeleteProcThreadAttributeList` is forwarded to `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.DeleteProcThreadAttributeList`.

OK, I then use my method again to resolve redirection of the virtual `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll` API set:

```
HMODULE hMM = ::LoadLibraryEx(L"api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll", 
    NULL, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES);
WCHAR buffModPath[MAX_PATH];
::GetModuleFileNameEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), hMM, buffModPath, _countof(buffModPath));
::FreeLibrary(hMM);
```

Which gives me `C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL`, that brings me back to where I started.

So how do I resolve this circular dependency to actual DLL address/entry point the way OS module loader does it?

Comment: this is well known things, but what you actual try get ?

Comment: if you want get dll where function actuall implemented - simply call `GetProcAddress` for it. and then can use returned address with `GetMappedFileName`. if want exactly dll base - `RtlPcToFileHeader`

Comment: @RbMm: Well, I'm also trying to understand what the loader does internally.

Comment: look for [ApiSetResolveToHost](https://github.com/DarthTon/Blackbone/blob/master/src/BlackBoneDrv/apiset.h#L236) - *ParentName* parameter. the same name `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0` can be converted to `kernel32` or `kernelbase` depend from *ParentName* parameter

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, I see `ApiSetResolveToHost` seems to be that undocumented API whose input changes in every version of Windows since 7. I'm curious though, if there's a documented way to resolve it? Also why doesn't `LoadLibraryEx`/`GetModuleFileNameEx` do it -- it was such an elegant solution that you came up with.

Comment: PS. I can't use `GetProcAddress` as I also need to know the function's IAT entry. Plus the module is not loaded into the process that I can call it from. And as `RtlPcToFileHeader` goes, it converts address to base address. No module name resolution.

Answer (score 4):

I think whatever happens if you `GetProcAddress` one of these exports is supposed to be a black box.

The PEB has a ApiSetMap member in Windows 7+ that contains set information that the loader uses. The format of this data has changed at least 3 times but the mapping is not just from "API-*.dll" to "*32.dll".

You can read the Microsoft patent of this concept [here](http://www.patentsencyclopedia.com/app/20140366045).